# Contain and display a java applet in wpf

Tags: java, c#, wpf, reflection, applet

I'm considering writing an application that requires me to display content contained in a third party java applet in a WPF window allowing the user to view and interact with said content, and *ideally* allowing me to use some form of reflection to retrieve information for access in WPF and also display information inside of the applet (hooking into its drawing method, presumably) from C#

I'm aware that the best solution would likely be to simply write the application in Java, but I'd much rather stick to what I know instead of investing many hours in getting acquainted with Java. After looking around for a few hours, I can't seem to come across any useful information on the topic myself.

Is there any way to go about this? Examples are appreciated where possible

Answer (score 0):

Information exchange is tricky, but if it just comes to "containing and displaying" - why not just show the java applet in a WebBrowser control?

Comment: I would take that approach but in an ideal world I'd be able to use some form of reflection to fetch some variables inside of the applet as well as drawing some information in specific parts of the applet.

If there's some way of doing that with a WebBrowser then that'd work, but to my knowledge that's not a thing.